# Prove an inequality concerning Kullback-Leibler Divergence

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, information-theory

For any distribution $P$ and $Q$ on $\mathcal{X}$ and any function $f:\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, prove the following inequality:
$$\mathbb{E}_{x\sim Q}[f(x)]\le \ln \mathbb{E}_{x\sim P}[\exp(f(x))]+KL(Q||P)$$
I have no idea on transforming the expectation to a Kullback-Leibler Divergence at all. Is there a simple proof on the inequality (for example, just using the knowledge of probability theory and calculas)? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This computation appears in the study of variational inference. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\log \mathbb{E}_{x\sim P}(f(x)) &\triangleq \log \int_x p(x) f(x) dx\\
&= \log \int_x q(x) \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}f(x) dx\\
&\geq \int_x q(x) \log \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}f(x) \right)dx\\
&= \int_x q(x) \log f(x) dx +\int_x q(x) \log \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \right)dx\\
&\triangleq \mathbb{E}_{x\sim Q}(\log(f(x)))-KL(Q||P),
\end{align}
$$

Comment: To note, the inequality is due to Jensen's, with concavity of $\log(\cdot)$.